# Cannot detect Connector Project version. Please specify version of Connector Project through Maven project property <connectorVersion>

Tags: maven, myeclipse

I have a maven project for a resource adapter.
MyEclipse shows the next error:
*Cannot detect Connector Project version. Please specify version of Connector Project through Maven project property .*

What does this error mean and how to fix it?